# npm create-react-app can't finished after waiting a long time

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

Anyone can help me why npm create-react-app on my windows computer can't finished? it's always ended up like this and never finish installation although i'm waiting for hours.

```
C:\Users\Best\Desktop>npx create-react-app my-app
npx: installed 98 in 44.022s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Best\Desktop\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\Best\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\babel-run
time\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Best\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Best\Desktop\my-app\node_modules\core-
js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react@16.13.1
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-dom@16.13.1
added 1602 packages from 751 contributors and audited 1606 packages in 668.379s

61 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Usually, It takes some time a little longer than you think to install the template. Maybe you have to clean the npm cache and reinstall the recommended node version.

Comment: @DushanRandika I'm trying to clean cache and reinstall recommended node version, it's still stuck and not finished until i;m waiting in hours.

Comment: Did you check you internet connection? Try to restart the router / Check down/up speed.

Comment: Do node -v to check if node is installed, npm -v to check if npm is also there, lastly possibly if all is good restart the machine I have had instances where that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

1. clean node cache or uninstall  node js from control panel
   and make sure to delete it especially from windows  registry            because even after uninstalling there may be some global packages and             dependencies which can  cause this issue .( this mainly happens with linux)

2)install node js (LTS version) and yarn  from its official websites
as you need node to run js in terminal , and yarn(and react) was developed by facebook to solve issues with node package manager

3)

```html
npx create-react-app new-app
or
yarn create react-app new-app
```

change directory and type  npx start to run your sample app via localhost

Answer (score 1):

There is another command to build react app,
maybe it will solve your problem.

```
npx create-react-app
```

Note to write npx instead of npm.

Comment: Thank you for notting me, is that good by now?

Comment: Yes spot on @Sara ;)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is may be caused by command prompt stalling. Follow the below steps to resume the process.

These steps should be followed after running `npx create-react-app my-app`

```
Steps:
1) Search for resource monitor in windows search
2) Go to CPU tab
3) Search for cmd.exe
4) Right click on it
5) Click on Resume Process.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use yarn instead of npm its more easy and less time for create react app

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Docs link https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#yarn

and if any doubts comment here

Answer (score 0):

Here the resource from React: [Create React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)

Summary:

1. Make sure you are already installing the latest version of the node.
2. Make sure the `sample` directory is didn't exist.
3. Open a terminal then run this command `npx create-react-app sample`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I solved it by setting npm proxy with the following commands:

```
npm config set proxy http://your-organization-proxy
npm config set https-proxy http://your-organization-proxy
npm config set proxy your, organization, no, proxy, urls
```

Make sure you keep the `http://` in the proxy URLs.

Answer (score 0):

After much time, I downloaded Nodejs **32 bit**. Unbelievably, that was the trick.